# DBScan tabulating Results

Tags: r, dbscan

I am working on sequencing data and I am looking to use DBscan to create clusters using the allele frequency paramter which is basically 0-100% of a gene mutation occuring. I'm comparing two time points per pattient which gives me the x and y parameters. I've played aroung with the eps and minPts values which is fine but the issue I'm having is tabulating the data I'm getting.

So I would like to know which genes are in the clusters which are being created by the program. I've had a look at documentation for DBscan and I can't seem to find the relevant code anywhere. Saying that, I am very much a total amateur with R so I might have missed something very simple.

I am using the "dbscan" package
This is what I run

```
#Curating df to have relevant columns plus gene names, and transforming to matrix
dbscanplot.1 <- Curated.1 %>% select(Gene.Symbol.y, Diag.Allele.Fraction, Rel.Allele.Fraction)

#removing gene names to create matrix
dbscanplotMATRIX.1 <- as.matrix(dbscanplot.1[,2:3])

#running dbscan
kNNdistplot(dbscanplotMATRIX.1, k = 5)
abline(h=5, col = "red", lty=2)

pairs(dbscanplotMATRIX.1, col = res$cluster + 1L)

fr <- frNN(dbscanplotMATRIX.1, eps = 1.3)
dbscan(fr, minPts = 3)

#plotting data
plot(dbscanplotMATRIX.1, col=res$cluster)
points(dbscanplotMATRIX.1[res$cluster==0,], pch = 3, col = "grey")
```

I would like to know what genes are in each cluster, so I would manipulate the `"dbscan(fr, minPts = 3)"` line?

I've tried  `db$cluster` as recommended below previously but the data that is generated is confusing as there are over a thousand data points being analysed.

An example is:
`[1]  0  1  2  3  0  4  0  0  2  2  2  5  2  2  2  0  2  0  1  0  4  0  4  2  4  4  2  2  0  2  0  4  2  4  4  6  7  4`

but with a huge number of data points. I guess I was wondering would it be possible to match this generated data with gene names.

**EDIT: I think I've solved my problem with Michael Hasler's help. I exported the dbscan results as a integer then added the new column to my origianl dataframe. It seems like it matches up with the dataframe results.**

```
clusters<-res$cluster
dbscanplot.1["Cluster"] <- clusters
```

Apologise it's a really simple solution but I am a complete novice!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation `? dbscan`:

```
 Value:

 An object of class 'dbscan_fast' with the following components:
   eps : value of the eps parameter.
   minPts : value of the minPts parameter.
   cluster : A integer vector with cluster assignments. Zero indicates
      noise points.
```

So you can get the cluster assignments in your code with:

```
db <-dbscan(fr, minPts = 3)
db$cluster
```

Comment: I've done previously, the issue is that the data I'm analysing has over a thousand points and the resulting data that is generated is just huge, is there a way of marrying up the cluster info with the gene symbols?